# Creating "new" objects on Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

recently i've been watching a video-tutorials of node.js. And on the part of "Object factory".

```
var foo = require("./module");
```

and he create an "new object" doing this

```
var myObject = foo();
```

now he can use all the methods within of foo module.
why he not use the "new" word?

```
var myObject = new foo();
```

Comment: Can you not access all of the methods by referencing foo itself without creating a new object?

Comment: A function can return an object with methods on it without being a constructor function.

Comment: This isn't a node.js thing but how JavaScript handles object creation and contructors. You can check out [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) and/or you can also read [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](http://amzn.to/1RagwFf), specifically [this section](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/fe5ee5db541c6a35b67561caaa5c125d99c5ab4c/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md#class-functions).

Comment: @Quentin yeah i get it!, `module.exports = function(){ return { hw : "Hello Wordl"}}`. without the `return` I need to use `new`, isn't?

Comment: @EzequielDurán — The function would need to be designed to be used with new. Simply leaving out return isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Take this for example:

```
function SomeClass() {}
SomeClass.prototype = {
    sayHi: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
};

function foo() {
    return new SomeClass();
}

foo() // => returns a new SomeClass object
```

In that case, `foo` is what they're referring to as a "factory" function, in that it is sort of like a type of factory that creates objects (just like in real life how factories create new objects; car factories, etc.)

It's also good for singletons:

```
(function() {
    var singleton;

    function SomeClass() {}
    SomeClass.prototype = {
        sayHi: function() {
            console.log('hello');
        }
    };

    function foo() {
        singleton = singleton || new SomeClass();
        return singleton;
    }

    window.foo = foo;
}());

foo(); // returns a new SomeClass
foo(); // returns the same SomeClass instance (not a new one). This is a singleton.
```

Node.js is just regular JavaScript, so in the example you've given, all you're doing is including the factory from a module and using it to create new objects (instances of "classes").

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of the new keyword could indicate they return a new object when you require it.